# ListView with TextView with background image

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a ListView with a lot of "rows". In each row, i have one TextView with a background image. When i scroll, the images of the rows mixes... they jump to another row with the scroll.
In have tried android:scrollingCache="false" and              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" but nothing.

The images are loaded dinamically.

Part of my  layout:

```
<LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/QueryList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="3px"
                android:layout_below="@id/NavigationTab"
                android:layout_above="@id/Query"
                android:gravity="top">
        <ListView 
              android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:scrollingCache="false"
              android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
```

and part of my code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ListContent holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expert_inflate_list, null);
            holder = new ListContent();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView iv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);   
            holder.avatar = iv;
            holder.onLine =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.online);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ListContent) convertView.getTag();
        }


        String rank = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= ListviewContent.get(position).getRanking(); i++ ) { rank+=">"; };

        holder.name.setText( ListviewContent.get(position).getCompleteName() + " " + rank );

        if (  ListviewContent.get(position).getAvatar() != null && !ListviewContent.get(position).getAvatar().equals("null") ) {
            holder.avatar.setBackgroundDrawable( avatars.get( ListviewContent.get( position ).getUserId() ) );
        }

        if (  ListviewContent.get(position).getOnline() ) {
            holder.onLine.setBackgroundDrawable( resources.getDrawable( R.drawable.arrow_on ) );
        } else {
            holder.onLine.setBackgroundDrawable( resources.getDrawable( R.drawable.arrow_off ) );               
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

"avatars" is a cache of Drawables
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
if (  ListviewContent.get(position).getAvatar() != null && !ListviewContent.get(position).getAvatar().equals("null") ) {
        holder.avatar.setBackgroundDrawable( avatars.get( ListviewContent.get( position ).getUserId() ) );
    }
```

with this:

```
holder.avatar.setBackgroundDrawable( avatars.get( ListviewContent.get( position ).getUserId() ) );
```

Is this what you meant?. If it works i can explain further. Not sure that's what you want...

Comment: Thank you for your response... My english is poor so my explanation was bad. THis line only check for the existence of the image. Not important. The result list at the start of the activity is:

Comment: [Avatar 1]   Name 1   Icon 1
[Avatar 2]   Name 2   Icon 2
[Avatar 3]   Name 3   Icon 3
...
[Avatar N]   Name N   Icon N


When i scroll:
[Avatar 1]   Name 1   Icon 1
[Avatar 2]   Name 2   Icon 2
[Avatar 1]   Name 3   Icon 1
...
[Avatar N]   Name N   Icon N

etc... The images mixes and the icons too. I think is a problem with the background and the cache but i have deactivated...
Thanks again.

Comment: Solved!!! You have reason. The problem was the missing "else" clause. What happen when "false": no icon...